# Adding dynamic image-URL in img src?

Tags: leaflet, javascript

I'd like to show a dynamic image (csv import) in my leaflet map, like:

```
.bindPopup("my dynamic imgage: " + <img src={row.myPicture}/>);
```

but can't figure out how to combine the img src with the dynamic content.

Comment: That looks like JSX. Are you using React?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In plain JS you make it like that:

```js
.bindPopup("my dynamic imgage: <img src='"+row.myPicture+"' />");
```

Comment: Thats it! Thank you so much mate